# Not able to populate the select drop down with JSON in reactJS

Tags: json, reactjs, react-select

I'm trying to fetch key "name" and its corresponding value using JSON in the drop down "Select" of reactJS. But it does not work when I'm executing my code. I have attached my code, Kindly have a look!

I have tried using componentDidMount to fetch the data by making API call. I am a beginner so I'm trying to figure out what ways can make it work.

```
class devName extends Component {
  state = {
    names: [],
    selectedName: "",
    validationError: ""
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8080/dashboard/get_names")
      .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        let namesFromAPI = data.map(name => { return { value: name, display: name } })
        this.setState({ names: [{ value: '', display: '(Select the site)' }].concat(namesFromAPI) });
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <div className="form-wrapper">
          <Toolbar />
          <form className="form">
            <label className="label1">Select Name from the drop down</label> <hr />
            <div>
              <Select 
                value={this.state.selectedName}
                onChange={(e) => this.setState({selectedName: e.target.value, validationError: e.target.value === "" ? "You must select a site name" : ""})}>
                {/* placeholder="Loading Site List..." > */}
                {this.state.names.map((name) => <option key={name.value} value={name.display}>{name.display} </option>)}
              </Select>
              <div style={{color: 'red', marginTop: '5px'}}>
              {this.state.validationError}
              </div>
              <br />
            </div>
            <label className="label1">Create New Name From Template</label>
            <hr />
            <div className="addButton">
              <button type="Submit">Add</button> <hr />
            </div>
            <div className="submitButton">
              <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default devName;
```

JSON CODE LOOKS LIKE:

```
[
    {
        "type": "state",
        "id": 2131,
        "temporaryEle": {},
        "name": "First Unit#1234 TON" .. and so on
    }
]
```

There is no error message. Though the desired result should be "Select Drop Down populates with : " Select one of the name please"

```
First Unit#1234 TON
Second Unit#8934 QON
Third Unit#6534 JON
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**
I've read one of your comments and it seems like you're having CORS issues with fetch.

Add the baseurl as proxy in your package.json file

```
// Package.json

{
  ...other configs,
  "proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:8080"
}
```

Then you'd call your fetch like so: `fetch('/dashboard/get_names').then((res) => {...})`

Resource for you to look at:

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/

**Old:**

According to your JSON data, you might have to destucture a level deeper on your object while mapping the data in `componentDidMount`

```js
let namesFromAPI = data.map(({name}) => { 
  return { value: name, display: name } 
})

// OR

let namesFromAPI = data.map(name => { 
  return { value: name.name, display: name.name } 
})
```

Comment: Yea I tried destructuring did not work. Could it be due to the connection issue between react and JSON? Is my Fetch request complete? should it be including headers and GET?

Comment: Hi, I tried adding the proxy url in package.json file also in django project but it throws the same error of CORS:
1 Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/dashboard/get_names' from origin 'https://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: Do you have the code on github I could look at? You could get around it in dev by having the CORS browser addons/plugins: "CORS Everywhere" and  "Allow-Control-Allow-Origin."

Comment: Hey, ya I cannot share as it's a private repo. But if you need specific set of code I can share that. Also, the CORS issue does not appear for other API fetch but for this specific.

Comment: The issue got resolved by adding a browser extension and turning it on: Moesif CORS. Somehow I'm facing issue "401 (Unauthorized)" while fetching the get API, which I think is because of the credentials time is getting out.

Comment: So the CORS issue I could fix by adding a header in package.json (under react) project.  
"headers": {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
  },

Answer (score 0):

Use destucturing on name parameter, you can implicitly return object from arrow function when you wrap it in () `data.map(({name}) => ({ value: name, display: name }))`

Comment: Thanks, I tried destructuring did not work. Could it be due to the connection issue between react and JSON? Is my Fetch request complete? should it be including headers and GET?

Comment: @ShivaniBali have you tried printing the value of `data` to console before executing map function? What's the server response when you open your link in a browser? `GET` is the default header

Comment: I tried to print it and it throws CORS error, which had occurred previously too but I resolved it by adding Chrome extension and a code snippet:CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = \ ('http://localhost:8000',)
The error this time says the same: Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/eai_shortcuts/get_sites' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Failed to fetch! I am looking into how can it be fixed because seems previous fix does not work this time.